# Quiero comparar de un ArrayList la primera posicion con la segunda, pero llega un momento que no funciona. Error IndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java, arraylist

Quiero comparar de un ArrayList la primera posición con la segunda, pero llega un momento que la condición del `if` que compara la `i` e `i+1`, peta. Creo que es porque llega un momento que se sale del ArrayList al escribir `i+1`, entonces como el arrayList ya no tiene mas contenido no tiene con que compararlo y de ahí el error. No se solucionarlo ayuda por favor.

```
public static void diaConMasCumples(ArrayList <Paciente> pacientesLista) {
        
        ArrayList numerosCumples = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList numerosContador = new ArrayList();
        
        for(int i = 0;i<pacientesLista.size();i++) {            
             for(int j = 0;j<32;j++) {
                 
                 if(pacientesLista.get(i).getAnoNacimiento().getDayOfMonth() == j) {
                    numerosCumples.add(j);
                    break;
                 }

             }
        }
        System.out.println(numerosCumples);
        
        Collections.sort(numerosCumples);
    
        System.out.println(numerosCumples);

        int dia = 0;
        int dias31 = 0;
        int contador = 0;           
        for(int i = 0;i<numerosCumples.size();i++) {
                    
            if(numerosCumples.get(i) == numerosCumples.get(i+1) && numerosCumples.get(i+1) == ) {
                    contador++;
            }else {
                    numerosContador.add(contador);
                    contador = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(numerosContador);
        System.out.println(numerosContador.size());
            
 
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es obtener el numero que mas veces se repite en tu ArrayList,podrías primero obtener la cantidad de veces que se repite individualmente cada numero (metodo 1) y después ir comparando para obtener el que mas veces se repite(metodo 2) y así obtener el día con mas cumpleaños

Ejemplo
teniendo el Arraylist con la fecha de los cumpleaños..

```
 ArrayList<Integer> cumples=new ArrayList();

  cumples.add(5);
  cumples.add(16);
  cumples.add(24);
  cumples.add(18);
  cumples.add(16);
```

//El metodo 1 regresa la cantidad de veces que aparece cada dia de cumple en el ArrayList

```
static int repeticiones(int n,ArrayList<Integer> lista){
   int cont=0;
   for (int i=0;i<lista.size();i++) {
      if(n==(int)lista.get(i))
        cont++;
   }
      return cont;  
}
```

//El metodo 2 compara las ocurrencias obtenidas apartir del primer metodo y regresa el dia de cumple con la mayor cantidad de ocurrencias

```
static int mayorRepetido(ArrayList<Integer> lista){
int mayor=(int)lista.get(0);
for (int i=1;i<lista.size();i++) {
    if(repeticiones(mayor,lista)<repeticiones((int)lista.get(i),lista)){
          mayor=(int)lista.get(i);
    }
}
return mayor;

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]